# Which package manager to use with ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 1.0)

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2015, nuget, asp.net-core, bower

I have a brand new asp.net 5 (soon to be re-branded ASP.NET Core 1.0), MVC 6 project and I want to add the angularjs package, as far as I can tell, there are 3 different methods 'built in' to Studio 2015 that are available to add the package.

1. [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) Package Manager
2. [Bower](http://bower.io/)
3. [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Each of these will install AngularJS into a different location on disk and each will might require further steps to be completed to make the angularjs package useful.

What, if anything, should I take into account when I decide which package manager I'm going to use for this task?
Are there advantages/disadvantages to using one particular manager vs another?

(in truth I wanted to install the Angular2 beta package, but it doesn't have a nuget package, so it didn't make quite as good an example)

Comment: For JavaScript I would go with npm. NuGet is best for .NET and there are rumors that bower is going through a crisis.

Comment: Hi Scott, was my answer below useful to you? If so, please mark as answer. :) Feel free to ask any follow-up questions!

Answer (score 1):

For client-side packages such as AngularJS, I had initially recommended only Bower when I responded to this.

But, based on the other comment about Bower and after asking for opinions from other devs, it seems like Bower may not be the top choice after all. That leaves NPM as another good option, since NuGet is not the top choice due to the reasons mentioned in the "long answer" below.

**Long Answer:**

In the past, developers would use NuGet for this, but it would take extra effort to get it up-to-date on NuGet. Bower (and NPM) exists for not just ASP.NET developers, but also for devs working with other languages and frameworks.

To reuse existing resources, Microsoft recommended the use of Bower for such client-side packages. For server-side packages (e.g. ASP.NET Core itself, EF, etc) and some client-side libraries, you should continue to use NuGet by populating your JSON-based configuration files.

Here's an old blog post (2014) from Scott Hanselman, on why you shouldn't be using NuGet for this:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx

This old blog post does recommend Bower, but new info suggests that Bower may have some long-term issues. So you *may* have to go with NPM in case Bower eventually disappears.

Hope that helps!